# How to find specific elements in a matrix (list of lists) in python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, matrix

I'm trying to understand matrix (list of lists) questions in python. I want to understand the basics of a matrix when it comes to python, so hopefully can I get some help.

The matrix I am looking at is:

```
[[5,6],[7,8]]
```

if

```
r = len(matrix) - 1
```

and

```
c = len(matrix[0]) - 1
```

is r = 8 and c = 7?

If you have two variables i and j and they both equal 0 what would the element for this be?

```
matrix[r - i][j]
```

Also if anyone has any insight in how to understand python interview problems that deal with matrices that would be really helpful!

Comment: Why do you think it would be 8 and 7? You don't really show any reasoning. Why are you interviewing for a language it doesn't seem like you know?

Comment: IndexError: index out of bounds

Comment: What are u asking?

Comment: @user3591723 if you aren't going to be helpful, don't comment.

Comment: Your values for r and c are dramatically wrong, so the only possible way for us to attempt to answer is to know what reasoning got you there otherwise all we can do is say you should probably look [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) and [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Comment: learn about the concept of list first

Answer (score -2, accepted):

When trying to solve matrices problems in python,use numpy arrays.The package is basically made for high performance matrix calculations.
When you loop through a matrix,we can access it by row,column.

Your r value is wrong.
It is a nested list.
So,matrix[0] is a list i.e [5,6] and len(matrix) gives the number of lists in the nested list i.e in ur case 2.
So, r = 2 - 1 = 1 and c = 2 - 1 = 1
As specified by you,i , j are 0.
Then matrix[1-0][0] = matrix[1][0] = 7.

My suggestion for you is to go through lists perfectly and then try solving problems.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! All the other comments above yours were really unnecessary so I appreciate your help.